TcpListener and TcpClient
I'm trying to connect TcpClient (client-side) and TcpListener (server-side) to send (more than one) data stream. I have a problem that I could not solve by reading docs and articles...
This is the method I use to start TcpListener (server-side):
public void StartListener()
{
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener listener = new(
        IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),
        15001);
        
    listener.Start();
    while (listen)
    {
        if (listener.Pending())
        {
            try
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    using (TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
                    using (NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
                    {
                        string message = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                            
                        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + message.Length + " bytes");
                    }
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{se.Message} ({se.ErrorCode})");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    } 
}

This is the code I use to send streams (client-side):
public void StartTcpClient()
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpClient = new();

        tcpClient.Connect(
            "127.0.0.1",
            15001);

        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = "This is and example."u8.ToArray();
        networkStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

My problem is in the line TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); when I start the client, a connection is established, but listener.AcceptTcpClient() always returns null. No errors or exceptions are thrown;, the code starts the next iteration.
Any idea?

Are you sure you want to use TCP directly? That can get rather complicated to do correctly, and there are plenty of higher level protocols and libraries that are much easier to use.

hi @JonasH. Can you give me some examples? I can evaluate the use of alternative methods...

"but listener.AcceptTcpClient() always returns null. No errors or exceptions are thrown;, the code starts the next iteration." There are 2 questions: since no errors or exceptions, how do you know that the method always returns null? What does the iteration refer to? That "while"? If so, because you run the method in a thread, the iteration won't stop definitely.

gRPC, for example; and even if you really want to write your own socket server (for a custom protocol) - that doesn't mean you need to actually deal with the network bits - Kestrel (the .NET web-server) can handle that for you; here's a RESP (think "Redis") server implemented via Kestrel: no socket code in sight! https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/toys/KestrelRedisServer/Program.cs

@shingo: very simple: using a breakpoint... And for "next iteration," I mean that the code starts to execute the next "while" block of code...

@MarcGravell. That is interesting, but your suggestions don't fit me. Do you know "flow-based programming"? I' like to do something, but using streams and not data packages...

Perhaps you did that in a wrong way, because according to the source code, AcceptTcpClient always returns a non-null object.

Why accept on a separate thread and not block until accepted and just run the client in a separate thread?

Wikipedia defines "Flow-based programming" as basically message passing. But byte streams are not messages, so you need to build message handling on top of TCP, something that is provided by most other protocols. So I don't really see why something like gRPC would not fit. I think gRPC also provides "stream of messages", that would likely be a far more useful abstraction than that of raw TCP.

Protocols can be broadly classified as request-response (Http & gRPC) or subscription-publication (MQTT, AMQP). Then there are libraries like Akka.net that might be useful if the actor model fits your use case. I would at least take a look at some of the above before trying to build my own.
